# Как сделать НЕ наследуемый класс в PHP?

Tags: php

Судари и сударыни, помогите советом. Как сделать класс НЕ наследуемым (PHP) ??
Гугление по ключевым словам "не наследуемый класс PHP", "какие бывают классы PHP", "наследование классов PHP" результатов не дало.
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> PHP 5 предоставляет ключевое слово final, разместив которое перед
>   объявлениями методов класса, можно предотвратить их переопределение в
>   дочерних классах. Если же сам класс определяется с этим ключевым
>   словом, то он не сможет быть унаследован. http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.final.php

```
final class BaseClass {
   public function test() {
       echo "Вызван метод BaseClass::test()\n";
   }

   // В данном случае неважно, укажете ли вы этот метод как final или нет
   final public function moreTesting() {
       echo "BaseClass::moreTesting() called\n";
   }
}
```

Comment: Не передать словами как я Вам благодарен, Дмитрий!

Comment: @O.J , на SO благодарят принятыми ответами :-) Нажмите на галочку слева от правильного ответа.

Comment: Прошу прощения, Михаил. Впредь буду внимательнее - не разобрался с управлением :)